# Why is my implementation of creating a movie in moviepy so inefficient?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, video, video-processing, moviepy

I am using moviepy, a python module for creating movies, to create movies of one pic of mike, followed by one pic of emily with a different song every 2 pictures. I implemented this in the following way:

```
clips = []
for i in range(n):
    audio = AudioFileClip(audiofiles[i]).set_duration(10)
    video1 = ImageClip(images_mike[i]).set_duration(5)
    video2 = ImageClip(images_emily[i]).set_duration(5)
    video = concatenate([video1,video2],method='compose')
    movie.set_audio(audio)
    clips.append(movie)
video = concatenate(clips,method='compose')
video.write_videofile('my_movie.mp4')
```

audiofiles, is a list of audio filenames. images_mike and images_emily are each lists of image filenames.

But this method is really really slow. video.write_videofile('my_movie.mp4') can take an hour to compile a 4 minute clip. Furthermore, I run into memory allocation errors when im trying to make a 10 minute clip. What is wrong with this implementation? Surely this isn't right.

I don't know if this is relevant, but im on a laptop, with 16gb ram and i7 processor.

Answer (score 3):

If it's the `write_videofile` that's slow, there is a `preset` argument that tells FFMPEG how much time to spend trying to optimize the compression.  The default is 'medium'. If you don't care how big your video file gets, try using `preset='ultrafast'`.  Per the documentation, the *quality* will not change no matter which option you choose, but the file could get a lot larger with a faster setting.

```
video.write_videofile('my_movie.mp4', preset='ultrafast')
```

`Choices are: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow, placebo.`

You can also use the `threads` argument, which defaults to `None`...try setting it to 2 or 3 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try using "method='chain' " in concatenate. It increased my speed from 4 it/s up to 20 it/s. Visually I had no differences in output at all however, this depends on your code and video you are making.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `ImageSequenceClip()` instead of `concatenate()`
eg:

```
ImageSequenceClip(/dir/where_your_pics/are, fps=20)
```

Also note, for some reason, `ImageSequenceClip()` is not yet documented on web ask ChatGPT about it for more details or check the GitHub repo for moviepy at .../io/ImageSequenceClip